# How to edit blog post template

Tags: blog

I want to ask how to edit blog post template. Where can I edit it, and add to each of blog post template table like this ?

[image]

Please help.

Comment: check this http://josharepoint.com/2014/07/14/dealing-with-style-the-sharepoint-2013-blog-template/

Answer (score 1):

1. Create copy of **/_layouts/xsl/blog.xsl**
2. Make your column changes to that file
3. Reference that on the blog web part in the **XSL Link** property

Details [here](http://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/how-to-customize-your-blog-subsite-in-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: But If I edit this or add new post it not show me this formated fields after edit or add.

Comment: How Could I achieve a template with editing content ?